# Dynamic variables matlab

Tags: matlab, eval

How can I access to dynamic variables in Matlab? I search for similar question but I didn't find.

Example (simplified):

```
for i=1:1
    aux3=(i-1)*50;

    delay_64_264(1,i) = mean(delay_64_264_', num2str(aux3), ' (:,3)*100;

end
```

What I want to do is mean of column 3 from variable `delay_64_264_0`.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`eval()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html).

But I recommend not doing this at all.  Use a multidimensional array, rather than lots of variables with slightly different names.

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from Oli's suggestions, see this piece of the MATLAB FAQ:

http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F

which shows how to use structures and cell arrays as an alternative to `eval`.