# Variable variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, eval

I have 30 txt files with data
And I want to create on the fly vectors from that files with the name of "file name"

```
pathforindependents = 'C:\MatLab\independent\'

independents = dir(fullfile(pathforindependents,'ind*.txt'))              

for i = 1:length(independents)

    filename = independents(i).name;
    r=regexp(filename,'\.','split');
    qnumber = r(2)
    qtitle=r(3)

    qpath = strcat(pathforindependents,filename)
    qdata = load(qpath)

    mtrxPrefix = 'mtrx_';

    v = strcat(mtrxPrefix,qtitle);

    eval(???????????????????????)

end
```

But I dont know how can I do it. No matter what I try Matlab gives me "Undefined function 'eval' for input arguments of type 'cell'." Error?

My data file structure is like

**ind.01.AGE.txt**

```
0
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
...
```

At the end I want to reach this

```
mtrx_AGE =
0
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
...
```

How can I do it ? Thank you.

Comment: Similar questions: [Dynamic variables matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7362265/97160), [Using Strcat to create dynamic variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9082031/97160)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put the variables in the base workspace, use [assignin](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/assignin.html):

```
 assignin('base', v, qdata);
```

As you can see in the [assignin documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/assignin.html), for certain assignment cases you may want to use [evalin](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/evalin.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can use fields within structures with sprintf to name variables on the fly:

```
for i = 1:100
   my_struct.(sprintf('A%s%i','filename',i)) = i^2
end
```

would make

```
my_struct.Afilename1 = 1
my_struct.Afilename2 = 4
my_struct.Afilename3 = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [Mathworks TechNote 1103](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1103.html) on why you should avoid using EVAL the way you do. Alternatives include cell arrays or structures.