# assigning a wildcard variable name to a determined variable name in MATLAB without eval

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, variable-assignment

Scenario:

For signal processing analysis, I'm receiving data from somebody else.  My standard practice if I have several data files, each representing a chunk of time, is to name the data vector `'data'` and the time vector `'time'` and not individuate each variable name, since they are isolated by files.  If I need to individuate them, I do it in the program that calls them.

However, I've recieved data from somebody who individuates them, so each variable is uniquely named, `'data10'`, `'data11'`.

All my routines and programs call on `'data'`.  Is there a way to change these variable names from `'dataxx'` to `'data'` without using `eval`?  My first thought was to try the assignin function, but it doesn't accept wildcard arguments for the `'value'` input.  Each time I load a file separately in its own structure, so it will never be a problem to use a wild card, ther will always only be one file that starts with `'data...'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading these variables from a `.mat`-file, you can use the `load` command with an output:

```
collectedData = load('dataVariables.mat');
```

`collectedData` has a field for each variable contained in the `.mat`-file. If you now want to access the variable `data10`, you can use dynamic field names to access it:

```
collectedData.(sprintf('data%i',10))
```

It is worth noting that `structfun` can be quite useful if you want to apply a function to each field of a structure without looping across field names.

Comment: Of course! I can't believe [I didn't think of that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097738/variable-variables-in-matlab/11098348#11098348)